# Python - parse inconsistently delimted data table

Tags: python, regex, email

I have a folder of emails that contain data that I need to extract and put into a Database. These emails are all formatted differently so I've grouped them by how similar their formats are. The following two emails bodies are examples of what I am trying to parse right now:

**1)**

[image]

**2)**

[image]

So in my attempts to extract the valuable data (the fish stock, the weight, the price, the sector, the date) I have tried several methods. I have a list of all possible 30+ stocks, and I run a RegEx on the entire email.

```
fishy_re = re.compile(r'({}).*?([\d,]+)'.format('|'.join(stocks)), re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

This RegEx, I was told, will search for any occurrence of a fish, then capture the next number that follows, and then group the two together.....and it does that job perfect. But when I tried adding an additional `.*?([\d,]+)` chunk to capture the NEXT number (the price, as seen in email 2) it fails to do that.

Is my RegEx that tries to grab the price wrong?

Also, in trying to deal with emails that have a `Package` deal (email 1), I again tried using RegEx to search for any line that has the word `Package` and then capture the next number that follows on that line.

```
word = ['package']
package_re = re.compile(r'({}).*?([\d,]+)'.format('|'.join(word)), re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

But that produces nothing....even when doing a simple command like:

```
with open(file_path) as f:
    for line in f:
        for match in package2_re.finditer(f.read()):
            print("yes")
```

It fails to print `yes`.

So is there a more effective way to extract the `Package` price information?

Thanks.

Comment: What format are these emails? If you look at the text wrapping on ie "SNEMA Yellowtail" or "GB Haddock East ACE" it looks like it is some sort of embedded table. You might be able to grab the table contents directly instead of trying to reconstitute it by text parsing.

Comment: Ok sorry if this is a dumb question but how do I check the text wrapping? I also thought it could be an embedded table but didn't really have any clue how to approach the table as a whole

Comment: I just meant, if you look at your picture above, "SNEMA Yellowtail" is text-wrapped and the numbers to the right are vertically centered. That looks like some form of automatic table layout. If you are using Outlook, that could be either an HTML table (most likely) or an embedded Excel spreadsheet (less likely but possible). You probably have the emails saved as .msg files - that's what you get if you drag-and-drop to save them. Before going further, can you confirm this?

Comment: Ohhh gotcha. Well right-clicking and checking its properties I see that it is a Thunderbird Document (.eml) file. Is that the information you wanted? Also, before trying to parse these emails, I did succeed in parsing HTML emails with BeautifulSoup... but looking at these I thought for sure they weren't the same format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created my own test email and parsed it like so:

```
import bs4       # BeautifulSoup html parsing
import email     # built-in Python mail-parsing library

FNAME = "c:/users/Stephen/mail/test.eml"    # full path to saved email

# load message
with open(FNAME) as in_f:
    msg = email.message_from_file(in_f)

# message is multipart/MIME - payload 0 is text, 1 is html
html_msg = msg.get_payload(1)
# grab the body of the message
body = html_msg.get_payload(decode=True)
# convert from bytes to unicode
html = body.decode()

# now parse to get table
table = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find("table")
data = [[cell.text.strip() for cell in row.find_all("td")] for row in table.find_all("tr")]
```

which returns something like

```
[
    ['', 'LIVE WGT', ''],
    ['BGE COD', '746', ''],
    ['GBW CODE', '13,894', ''],
    ['GOM COD', '60', 'Package deal $52,500.00'],
    # etc
]
```

Comment: Jesus. In less than 10 lines of code you've accomplished more than what I could in 100's of lines and many hours. I guess that's why you're an expert and I'm a beginner. So I like to ask follow up questions to understand it all better if that's ok: so I've tried using that `email` module but it never worked for me due to errors and strange encoding messages all the time, I would then have to save emails as txt files just to get at the text in them...but I think it's the line `body = html_msg.get_payload(decode=True)` that solved this problem. Right?

Comment: ....because I've seen (and tried) that command `a = msg.get_payload()` a lot of times but it never succeeded. But so basically, this code uses the `email` module to open the email, captures the body of the email and "decodes" it so it can be read (I think), and then we use BeautifulSoup because it is in fact an embedded HTML table and we simply find the table (`"table"`) and extract cells (`"td"`) with data in them with `cell.text.strip()`...in a nut shell... Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `msg` is a recursive structure - you may have to play around with it a bit to find the parts you are looking for. In the test email I created, `get_payload(0)` was the text version of the email, `get_payload(1)` was the html version (but base64 encoded). The first decode converts from base64 to bytes, the second from bytes to unicode.